# shuffling the 2d array deck which represents the 52 cards

Tags: arrays, c, shuffle

i have this program that prints th2 52 cards of a deck in order and then should print them randomly shuffled. I tried using many ways, but this one looked the most logically correct for me so Can you please tell me my mistake in shuffling and a solution to fix it, so my program will print the 52 cards shuffled.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DECK_SIZE 52
#define SUIT_SIZE 4
#define FACE_SIZE 13

 char* suit[SUIT_SIZE] = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};
 char* face[FACE_SIZE] = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", 
"Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

char* deck[SUIT_SIZE][FACE_SIZE];

char * card_name_create(char* face, char* suit){
size_t face_len = strlen(face);
size_t suit_len = strlen(suit);
size_t of_len = 4;
char of[5] = " of ";
// The size id the size of two strings, than the size of " of " and the '\0'
char * full_name = malloc(sizeof(char)*(face_len+suit_len+of_len+1));

for (size_t i = 0; i < face_len; i++){
    full_name[i] = face[i];
}

for (size_t i = face_len; i < face_len+of_len; i++){   
    full_name[i] = of[i-face_len];
}

for (size_t i = face_len+of_len; i < face_len+of_len+suit_len; i++){
    full_name[i] = suit[i - (face_len+of_len) ];
}

full_name[face_len+of_len+suit_len] = '\0';
return full_name;
}

void initialiseDeck(){
for (int i = 0; i < SUIT_SIZE; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < FACE_SIZE; j++){
        char * c = card_name_create(face[j],suit[i]);
        deck[i][j] = c;
    }   
  }
 }

void display(){
for(int i = 0; i < SUIT_SIZE; ++i)
for(int j = 0; j < FACE_SIZE; ++j)
printf("%s\n", deck[i][j]);
}

 void shuffleDeck(){
int size = DECK_SIZE;
if (size > 1){
    int i;  
    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++){
    int j = rand() % DECK_SIZE; 
    const char* temp = deck[j];
    deck[j] = deck[i];
    deck[i] = temp;
    }
}
}

int main(){
initialiseDeck();
printf("=========================");
printf("Cards Without Shuffling - ");
printf("=========================\n");
display();

srand (time(NULL));
shuffleDeck();

printf("cards after shuffling\n");
int p;
for (p = 0; p < DECK_SIZE; p++) {
    printf("%i: %s\n", p, deck[p]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please search `c shuffle card deck` using the search features of this site.

Comment: @KenWhite i searched and thats where i got my solution from but for some reason it not working

Comment: The following will not work as you seem to expect: `size_t face_len = strlen(face); size_t suit_len = strlen(suit);` as both are arrays of strings, not single strings,

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be shuffling anyway, there is no point in separating the cards by suit and rank... you should just have a 1-dimensional array `int deck[DECK_SIZE];`, and you can shuffle it with a function like this:

```
// Caller should seed the PRNG before calling this function, using srand
int *shuffle(int deck[], const int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        int j = rand() % (size - i) + i;
        int tmp = deck[i];
        deck[i] = deck[j];
        deck[j] = tmp;
    }
    return deck;
}
```